# Simple JavaScript URL Routing RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, url, routes

I'm trying to write a very basic URL router. I define a "routes" object that contains location paths and corresponding "module names."

Upon a full page load (no hash or pushState needed in this scenario), I want to look at the routes and find the corresponding module value, if it exists.

I'm having some trouble with my code.

```
(function() {

    return {

        routes: {
            '/': 'home',
            '/about': 'about',
            '/about/team': 'aboutTeam',
            '/about/team/:member': 'aboutMember'
        },

        init: function() {

            var url = location.pathname;

            for (var route in this.routes) {

                if (this.routes.hasOwnProperty(route)) {

                    if (url.match(this.regex(route))) {

                        // return & load module
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        regex: function(route) {

            return new RegExp(route.replace(/:[^\s/]+/g, '([\\w-]+)'));
        }

    }.init();

})();
```

The above code doesn't work well at all. (Obviously.) Landing on the page ***/about/team/jim*** will return all four pre-defined routes in this example. (And I can see why, just struggling with a solution.)

I'm not great with regular expressions. I snagged what I have above from here: [Javascript routing regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805441/javascript-routing-regex). I'm looking for advice and guidance. Am I even taking the right approach, overall?

Comment: The routes should be iterated in reversed order, and break out of the loop at the first match

Comment: @Himmel - No, `new RegExp()` takes a string argument and returns a regex object.

Answer (score 6):

[jsFiddle](http://jsbin.com/vulowurama/2/edit?js,console)

```js
console.clear();

(function() {

  var routes = { // initial config
    '/': 'home',
    '/about': 'about',
    '/about/team': 'aboutTeam',
    '/about/team/:member': 'aboutMember'
  };
  // parse and recreate config for use
  routes = Object.keys(routes)
    // sort longest path first
    .sort(function(a,b){ return b.length - a.length; })
    // convert into more usable format
    .map(function(path) {
      return {
        // create regex
        path: new RegExp("^" + path.replace(/:[^\s/]+/g, '([\\w-]+)') + "$"),
        module: routes[path]
      };
    });
  // == [{ path: /^\/about\/team\//:([\w-]+)$/, module: "aboutMember" },  ...]


  // fake url for testing
  var url = "/about/team/jim";

  // loop through all routes, longest first
  for (var i = 0, l = routes.length; i < l; i++) {  
    // parse if possible
    var found = url.match(routes[i].path);
    if (found) { // parsed successfully
      console.log("module: " + routes[i].module); // module to load
      console.log("args:", found.slice(1)); // arguments for module
      break; // ignore the rest of the paths
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: what about optional params? like /about/team/:member?

Answer (score -2):

You might be interested by [Frontexpress router](https://github.com/camelaissani/frontexpress). I coded this library.

```
const app = frontexpress();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {});
app.get('/about', (req, res) => {});
app.get('/about/team', (req, res) => {});
app.get('/about/team/:member', (req, res) => {
   const member = req.params.member;
   // your front-end logic here
});

app.listen();
```

More code samples [here](https://github.com/camelaissani/frontexpress)